# Itemize spacing

Tags: spacing, itemize

I don't use LaTeX that much, so I'm really clumsy with this stuff.

I've being searching for what I needed but since it appears there're no examples (or maybe I'm just bad at this) I decided to ask here.

I'm using some code that was giving to me in class, but I want to modify the way the itemize is looking.

[image]

```
\documentclass[final,letterpaper,twocolumn,authoryear,11pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
Donde,
\begin{itemize}  
\itemsep=0ex \itemindent=1cm 
\item[$K^B_A$:]  Constante de equilibrio químico, adim.
\item[$m_{A,liquid}$:] Concentración de A en la solución, mol/m\textsuperscript{3}.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I would like `m_{A,liquid}` to start just underneath `K^B_A` with the same spacing and, if it is possible, to make `mol/m^3` move just underneath "Concentración".

Hope you could understand my question and help me!

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). I don't seem to have the same spacing. Can you please expand your example, to a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Sorry beginner's mistake, my bad
`\documentclass[final,letterpaper,twocolumn,authoryear,11pt]{elsarticle}` 
and I was trying this
`\usepackage{enumitem}`

Comment: try and edit your own post, please, and include that there too.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Think the edit work, I just try it in a blank space. Sorry the inconvenience.

Comment: I expanded my comment, please read all of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this, with `enumitem` and `enumerate`?

```
\documentclass[final, letterpaper, twocolumn, authoryear, 11pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,margin=2.5cm, showframe}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

Donde,
\begin{enumerate}[wide, itemsep=0pt, leftmargin =*,widest={$m_{A,\mathrm{liquid}}$}]
  \item[$K^B_A$:] Constante de equilibrio químico, adim.
  \item[$m_{A,\text{liquid}}$:] Concentración de A en la solución, mol/m\textsuperscript{3}.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `\text` instead of `\mathrm`?

Comment: Maybe. I'm not sure whether it changes the inter-letter spacing.

Comment: Actually, question here, why did you guys change `$m_{A,liquid}$` for `$m_{A,\text{liquid}}$` or `$m_{A,\mathrm{liquid}}$`? just for aesthetics? @Bernard your answer work perfect, it all resumes in the way I wrote the equation that was above, because I need the nomenclature to match

Comment: `liquid` alone is  typed as the succession of variables `l,i,q,u,i,d` (with the inter-letter  spacing for variables), not as a word, and in italic. If  for some reason, you absolutely want it to be italic, you can us `\textit{liquid}`.

Answer (score 5):

I think a table is more suitable for you:

```
\documentclass[final,letterpaper,twocolumn,authoryear,11pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}>{$}c<{$}X@{}}
K^B_A&Constante de equilibrio químico, adim.\\
m_{A,\mathrm{liquid}}&Concentración de A en la solución \si{mol/m^{3}}\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Produces

[image]

---

**Recommendations**

I would recommend

1. making the environment into a float, i.e. surrounding the `tabularx` with `\begin{table} ... \end{table}`
2. Abbreviate `liquid` to `liq.`
3. Read some resource for learning basic LaTeX (browse around the most voted questions)

---

**NOTES AND USAGES**

I would just like to point out:

- I added spanish babel (I think the language is spanish)
- I added `fontenc` and `inputenc` to support T1 fonts and UTF-8 input encoding
- I added `siunitx` to space correctly the unit of measure
- I added `\mathrm{liquid}` because you are typesetting in math, and that's how the words come out in roman font and correctly spaced. `\text` would've produced the same here, but in general uses the text font, thus not always yields the roman font. (Thanks to @barbarabeeton)
- I added `tabularx` to have the autoexpanding X column in tables (read the package documentation)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I just change `\textwidth` to `\columnwidt` because it suited me better. You have save me some format points in my score :)

Comment: @Eli Yes, of course. `\columnwidth` is better, I'll change that

Comment: actually, `\text` will follow the current text style, so if you're using it within the scope of a theorem, the result will be italic (but not spaced like a string of variables).  if something is *always* to be upright, then `\mathrm` is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Two alternatives to `enuitem` and `tabular`-like environments:

1) The `desclist` package:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{desclist}
\begin{document}

\begin{desclist}{}{:}[$m_{A,\,liquid}$ ]
\item[$K^B_A$] Constante de equilibrio químico, adim. 
\item[$m_{A,\,liquid}$] Concentración de A en la 
                        solución, mol/m\textsuperscript{3}.
\end{desclist}
\end{document}
```

2) Just for fun, reinvent the wheel without packages and without lists. Instead of an environment, just a  macro with two arguments for each item:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newlength\anchod
\settowidth{\anchod}{$m_{A,\,liquid}$: }
\def\describe#1#2{{\par\noindent\makebox[\anchod][l]%
{$#1$:}#2\hangindent\anchod\par}}
\begin{document}
\describe{K^B_A}{Constante de equilibrio químico, adim.} 
\describe{m_{A,\,liquid}}{Concentración de A en la 
solución, mol/m\textsuperscript{3}.}
\end{document}
```

In this case there are no more vertical spaces around each fake item that those of normal paragraphs. If that is not enough, you can change it locally with:

```
   {\setlength{\parskip}{\itemsep} 
    \describe{...}{...}
    ...  
    \describe{...}{...} 
    Normal paragraph\par}`
```

The `\itemsep` is to mimic the spacing of true lists, but, of course, you can change `\itemsep` to anything else. Or you can add some spacers like `\bigskip` in the macro to avoid change the paragraphs skips.