# I am trying to have multiple nomenclatures for different sections within an article class document

Tags: sectioning, nomenclature

I am writing an article using lyx and I am wanting to have different nomenclatures in each section as some symbols are used on multiple occasions but have different meanings. I looked through documentation for the nomencl module but couldn't find a code that would allow me to create a second nomenclature with different definitions within it. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get around this issue? Even if its a way to show in one nomenclature that in section 1 sigma denotes a different term to the sigma in sections 2 if that makes sense.

[image: Example]

Comment: Can you please give an example, even a sketch? Then it may be easier to see what you want to achieve. Thanks

Comment: @MS-SPO I have added a very simple example that i have created to hopefully make it easier to show what I want to achieve. Thanks

Comment: As far I see,  you need just a `\section{Nomenclature)` a some kind of tabular, description list or [some mimicking that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364882/11604).

Comment: Thank you @Fran for that fix. Do you know of a way using the list/toc nomenclature insert in lyx or is this the only way to do this?

Comment: @Harr73 afaik,  LyX use `nomencl`, that allow to make symbols subgroups  (see the manual)  but for a single list.  As I am not sure of you want exactly, my suggest is (1) first take a tour by topics  [glossary](https://www.ctan.org/topic/glossary) and  [aconym](https://www.ctan.org/topic/acronym) of CTAN, to have a rough idea of what else you can do a package about this topics,  and then (2) remember this rule: keep it simple!