# How to split a large text in a cell table in multiple pages

Tags: tables, pdftex, longtable

I have this code:

```latex
\begin{tabular}{l}

\textbf{Descrição:}
 \parbox[t]{13cm}{TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE
TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE FDSFSDFSDFSD} \\ 

\textbf{Integrantes:}XXXX\\ 
\textbf{Entidades Participantes:} XXXX\\ 
\textbf{Fonte de Financiamento:} XXXX\\ 
\textbf{Período:} XXXX\\ 
\end{tabular}
```

And this result:

[image]

This doesn't show all the content. I need to break the text to show it in the next pages.

Comment: remove the tabular and parbox, use a `description` list

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This is cool! Thanks! But can I 'remove' the words under the word 'Descrição'

Comment: @RxT There are some destription-like alternatives that do that. See for instance [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364882/11604) and   [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/527503/11604).

Comment: Please don't put solutions in the question, you could post that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @David Carlisle and @Fran, I did:

```latex
\begin{description}[leftmargin=2.4cm]

\item[\textbf{Descrição:}] \mbox{} \\ TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE
TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTETESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE FDSFSDFSDFSD

\item[\textbf{Integrantes:}] \mbox{} \\ EXEMPLO EXEMPLO, EXEMPLO EXEMPLO, EXEMPLO EXEMPLO, EXEMPLO EXEMPLO, EXEMPLO EXEMPLO, EXEMPLO EXEMPLO, EXEMPLO EXEMPLO, EXEMPLO EXEMPLO, EXEMPLO EXEMPLO, EXEMPLO EXEMPLO
\item[\textbf{Entidades Participantes:}] \mbox{} \\ YYYYYY YYYYYY, YYYYYY YYYYYY, YYYYYY YYYYYY, YYYYYY YYYYYY, YYYYYY YYYYYY, YYYYYY YYYYYY, YYYYYY YYYYYY, YYYYYY YYYYYY, YYYYYY YYYYYY, YYYYYY YYYYYY, YYYYYY YYYYYY, YYYYYY YYYYYY, YYYYYY YYYYYY, YYYYYY YYYYYY, 
\item[\textbf{Fonte de Financiamento:}] \mbox{} \\ XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX
\item[\textbf{Período:}] \mbox{} \\ ÇÇÇÇÇÇ ÇÇÇÇ, ÇÇÇÇÇ ÇÇÇÇ
\end{description}
```

This is not so beautiful yet, but it is way better!

[image]

Comment: You can accept own answer ;-)

Comment: @Zarko not yet :(